# jQuery change visibility browser performance issue

Tags: jquery, performance, cross-browser

I have one question on jQuery and JavaScript performance.  My application is using layout with multiple tabs and to switch between them, I have written this code:

```
function openTab(id, holder) {
   $("#" + holder).children(".tab").addClass("visHidden");
    $("#" + id).removeClass("visHidden");
   $("#"+holder+" .tab-nav").removeClass("tab_navAkt");
   if (/^\d*$/.test(id)) {                                 
      $("#"+holder+" ." + id).addClass("tab_navAkt");
   }
}
```

It does this: adds class with `visibility:hidden` to all tabs, then removes this class from tab which I want to see and then it sets tab-control element as active if it is needed.
My question is how is it possible that this code takes about 3ms in Firefox or Chrome and about 500ms in Internet Explorer 7 & 8 ? The average data size in tab is 500kb and that isn't too much I think.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This should probably be migrated to the [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 1):

IE is generally slower as compared to FF and Chrome in JavaScript execution. However you can optimize your code and try the performance in IE. Try this.

```
function openTab(id, holder) {
   var $holder = $("#" + holder);
   $holder.children(".tab").addClass("visHidden");
   $("#" + id).removeClass("visHidden");
   $holder.find(".tab-nav").removeClass("tab_navAkt");
   //you can get rid of this check. jQuery will addClass only if it finds the element
   //if (/^\d*$/.test(id)) {                                 
      $holder.find(" ." + id).addClass("tab_navAkt");
   //}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it's the regex causing the issue.  Also, you could rewrite that using `.show()` and `.hide()`.

```
   $("#" + holder).children(".tab").hide();
   $("#" + id).show().addClass("tab_navAct");
```

Comment: but i have read an article about show/hide and it said that show/hide is slower than changing classes

Comment: looking at the src it's just setting the native properties for visibility so I doubht it's really slower than addClass https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js#L18

Comment: well it is not, it is changing the display property and it is slower, because it changes the page layout and the browser hav to save data from hidden element to restore them again. According to this article http://www.learningjquery.com/2010/05/now-you-see-me-showhide-performance